# How to Stop Powershell Script while Running React

Tags: reactjs, powershell, npm

I am running some basic files using `React` in `Powershell` and want to stop the script.  When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it only states *stopping* endlessly.

I end up having to exit out of the `Powershell` and use task manager to exit out of the `npm` scripts.  I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> and that does not make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0):

Try running <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Apparently there's an issue regarding sending SIGINTS to processes in Windows such as a nodejs server. For further reference if that doesn't help, see [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill). That should work without any exceptions regarding graceful termination of tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens when I do that.